# Post title not displaying in magento blog

Tags: magento, post, blogs, title

I install magento extension `"Neotheme_nBlog"` for blog, But it is not displaying post title. It displaying like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/neotheme/blog/post/summery.phtml**

I change this code

```
<div class="page-title post-title"><h2><a href="<?php echo $this->getPost()->getReadMoreUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->getPost()->getTitle(); ?></a></h2></div>
```

With this

```
<h2><a href="<?php echo $this->getPost()->getReadMoreUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->getPost()->getTitle(); ?></a></h2>
```

remove `<div class="page-title post-title">`

Now post title is displaying.